# "Pick up something" or "pick something up"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, phrasal-verbs

I have difficulties with word order:

> - I have picked up the pencil from the floor. [says my dictionary]
>     ?I have picked the pencil up from the floor. [could be?]
> - ?I will pick up it. [sounds weird]
>     I will pick it up. [sounds right to me]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This from the ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’:

> Where the direct object is a pronoun (1), it is usually placed between the
>   verb and the particle (over 90 per cent of the time) . . . However,
>   when the direct object is an indefinite pronoun (2), it is often placed
>   after the adverbial particle . . . When the direct object is a full
>   noun (3), there is more variation in its placement.

For Example:

1. Pick it up.
2. Pick up something.
3. Pick the pencil up. Pick up the pencil.

Answer (score 0):

Your first, second, and fourth examples are all good and resemble sentences people say all the time.

Number three, "I will pick up it", definitely sounds strange to me, though I really can't say why. If you replaced "it" with something specific, like, "I will pick up the pencil", it would be considered perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0):

If "something" is short, you may use either one.  But if it is long, put the "up" just after the "pick".

> Pick up from the floor all the pencils, books, dolls, and blocks.

more easily understood than

> Pick all the pencils, books, dolls, and blocks up from the floor.