# Shut down the computer, or shut the computer down?

Tags: verbs

I'm not sure what they're called, but I notice that 2-word verbs can be arranged around and yet both sound okay.

> Have you tried out baseball yet?
>
> Have you tried baseball out yet?

or

> Do you want to take out your burger?
>
> Do you want to take your burger out?

or

> Remember to shut down the computer.
>
> Remember to shut the computer down.

Which usage is correct?

Comment: Both are correct.

Comment: They're all grammatical, correct, and idiomatic. Nothing wrong with any of them; they only differ slightly in the nuances of what they emphasize (which, in speech, would be further underscored with tone and stress). BTW, in the US at least, we don't ask "*Do you want to take you food **out***?", we ask "*Do you want to take your food **to go***?", though restaurants where you can do that are still termed "take out places", and the food "take out food".

Comment: English has all along been splitting hairs over split infinitive/prepositions conundrum. There are a lot of posts on this right here on a ELU at least since Q.#16, Aug 05, 2010.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["put X down to" vs. "put down X to": subjects of verbs with two particles](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75792/put-x-down-to-vs-put-down-x-to-subjects-of-verbs-with-two-particles). Also [Is it correct to change the common structure in these phrasal verbs?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80918/) and [“Pick up something” or “pick something up”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64867/)

Comment: Thanks, @Fumble I'm unable to  copy-paste urls from my phone.