# Pick up someone vs Pick someone up?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-order, phrase-order

When referring to toddles/infants, we say:

> Example 1) Pick up the baby.

But when my friend asks me a favor, they would say:

> Example 2) Can you pick John up from the bus stop?

or...

> Example 3) Can you pick up John from the bus stop?

I always thought that example 1 is correct because it involves an actual act of picking up someone and *carrying* it. But between examples 2 and 3, example 2 is correct and example 3 is incorrect. Why, because you *do not* actually carry John around. However, I have noticed many people using Example 3 as the correct way to describe the action.

Between examples 2 and 3, which is the correct way?

---

**Duplicate Alert?**

- [“Pick up something” or “pick something up”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/64867/49754)

This question appears to be duplicate but [that question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/64867/49754) is more related to the actual action of lifting an object and carrying it. And hence, I think my question is not truly a  duplicate. Please correct me if it is duplicate.

Comment: This is purely a matter of syntax, which Barrie's answer addresses well.

Answer (score 0):

Either 2 or 3 is correct.

In the phrasal verb *pick up*, the object can come before or after the preposition. Oxford Learner's Dictionary provides this notation for the relevant meanings of *[pick up](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/pick-up?q=pick%20up)*:

> pick somebody <-> up
>
> pick somebody/something <-> up

The <-> [means](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/about/english/labels) that the word before and after can appear in reverse order. Technically, in example 1 I can either "pick the baby up" or "pick up the baby."  Similarly, if I want someone to drive to the bus stop to bring John home, I can put *John* before or after the preposition:

> Can you pick up John ...
>
> Can you pick John up ...

The related question you link to merely adds an additional restriction: a pronominal object immediately follows *pick*. John is not a pronoun.